# Need to know Joomla Session timer data type

Tags: session, joomla

I have been looking under database of joomla. There I found under gu94g_session table, time column which is having value 1377499731. What does it mean. how I can decode this time. Would appreciate help.[image]

Comment: check admin section(Global configuration) you can set the session time limit

Comment: Yeah I know how to increas the time limit, its under system configuration-> System tab. My question is what is the meaning of the integer value given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time` column contains the Unix timestamp at the time of the records creation.

In Joomla! 2.5+ and 3.x+ the `time` column of `#__session` is set to value returned by PHP's `time()` i.e. the current Unix timestamp.

When sessions are stored in the database, the `/libraries/joomla/sessions/storage/database.php` file creates a record using this SQL query:

```
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->update($db->quoteName('#__session'))
            ->set($db->quoteName('data') . ' = ' . $db->quote($data))
            ->set($db->quoteName('time') . ' = ' . $db->quote((int) time()))
            ->where($db->quoteName('session_id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($id));
```

The time is set with this line:

`->set($db->quoteName('time') . ' = ' . $db->quote((int) time()))`

Answer (score 1):

Its time stamp value of the current date time.

When the user get logged in in the site front end or back end a corresponding session is created with their login time like `strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"))` and save that on the time column Then based on the back end value its check expiry and clear session.

I think now its clear for you..

Comment: If you look at the OP's screenshot you'll see it's actually a large `int` containing the Unix timestamp equal to the time the record was created, not a `strtotime(date("Y-m-d- h:i:s"))`

Comment: @cppl I agree with your answer its create using time() but the result of time() and strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s")) are same i am not saying its created with strtotime(date()) function its like that that means we can create timestamp with different function in php

Comment: My bad, I looked at the format in `date()` and completely skipped the `strtotime()`. I'm just used to calling `time()` for a direct "now" value and `date()` when I need a different one.